# How should code that uses a Golfer object may therefore ask for a specific golf club to be operated by referring to that GolfClub by name

Tags: c#

A quick brief of the program that i have already done.

**Golfer:** A Golfer can be equipped with a Golf Club using the PickUp method; the golf club is
then stored in the Golfer’s club field. The Golfer’s holding property is true when its golf club
field is not null. When the Golfer is told to Swing, the following occurs:

1. If the Golfer is holding a golf club:
   “Breathe and focus” is printed to the console. (b) The Golfer tells its club to swing.
2. Else…
   “Where is my caddy?” is printed to the console.

**GolfClub:** Any golf club that can be swung; a GolfClub can also be held by a Golfer. GolfClub
is an abstract base class.

**Putter:** A Putter is a GolfClub that, when swung, prints “putt putt putt”.

**SandWedge:** A SandWedge is a GolfClub that can be swung 5 times before it is thrown in
frustration. (The constructor sets the swing counter to 5 and calling the Throw method resets
the play counter to 5.) When a SandWedge is swung, it does one of two things: if the remaining swing count is larger than zero, it prints “I am in my happy place” and the swing count is
decremented by one; otherwise it prints “hand me my hockey stick”.

**My problem:**

Code that uses a Golfer object may, therefore, ask for a specific golf club to be operated by referring
to that GolfClub by name. I'm not expected to get input from the user, just embedding it directly in Program.cs is totally fine. So basically a golfer wants to play, either select putter or sandwedge.

My code:

Program.cs

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private enum GolfKind
        {
            Putter, SandWedge
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Golfer golfer = new Golfer();
            Putter putt = new Putter();
            SandWedge sandwedge = new SandWedge();

            golfer.PickUp(putt);
            golfer.PickUp(sandwedge);

            if (golfer.Holding == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Breate and Focus");
                golfer.Swing(putt);
                golfer.Swing(sandwedge);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Where is my Caddy?");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

GolfClub.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public abstract class GolfClub
    {
        public GolfClub() { }
        public abstract void Swing();
    }
}
```

Golfer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Golfer
    {
        private List<GolfClub> _clubs; 
        public Golfer()
        {
            _clubs = new List<GolfClub>();
        }
        public bool Holding
        {
            get
            {
                if(_clubs.Count() != 0)
                 {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        public void PickUp(GolfClub club)
        {
            _clubs.Add(club);
        }
        public void Swing(GolfClub club)
        {
            foreach (GolfClub gc in _clubs)
            {
                if (gc == club)
                {
                    gc.Swing();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SandWedge.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class SandWedge : GolfClub 
    {
        private int _count;
        public SandWedge()
        {
            _count = 5;
        }
        public override void Swing()
        {
            while(_count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am in my happy place");
                _count--;
            }
            if (_count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hand me my hockey stick");
            }
        }

        public void Throw()
        {
            _count = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Putter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Putter : GolfClub
    {
        public Putter () {}

        public override void Swing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("putt putt putt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's homework

Comment: It is not homework, because it first time I'm using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`IDictionary<string, GolfClub>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to associate a name with a golf club. Provide the name as a new argument for the `PickUp()` method. Then use a string argument in the `Swing()` method to find the right club.

```
public class Golfer
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, GolfClub> _clubs = new Dictionary<string, GolfClub>();

    // [...]

    public void PickUp(GolfClub club, string name) {
        _clubs.Add(name, club);
    }

    public void Swing(string name) {
        _clubs[name].Swing();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the string name work in the Program.cs without user input ?

Comment: Can you do it with List array, please?

Comment: @Soran You can use a fixed string to name the club, you don't need any user input. It would be something like `golfer.Pickup(putt, "MyPutter");` and then you can use `golfer.Swing("MyPutter");`. It is possible to use an array if you add a property to the `Club` class which defines the name of the `Club`. After that you can use `Single()` to get the club by the given string name.

Comment: @Soran Yes. You can save the name in a new property `public string Name {get; }` inside the `GolfClub` class. Then you can use `_clubs.Single(it => it.Name == name).Swing();` to get the club with the given name. Keep in mind that the name is now stored in the club and not with the golfer anymore.